# esp8226 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to make a UI for esp8226 html js, ajax everything works fine but when I try to upload the firmware(uxx.bin) file it doesn't work.
Reference : [https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link/blob/master/html/flash.js](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link)

Note : I am connected to same network using wifi and the html page loads quite good.

I am trying to upload two files 1 --> uxx.bin
once it uploads redirect to next page and upload 2 --> uyy.bin

Here is the code

Html

```
<form id="file-form" action="uxx.bin" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="file-select" name="user[]" multiple/>
  <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>

var form = document.getElementById('file-form');
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Update button text.
  uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
var files = fileSelect.files;
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];

  // Check the file type.
  if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  // Add the file to the request.
  formData.append('user[]', file, file.name);
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'uxx.bin', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // File(s) uploaded.
    uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Upload';
  } else {
    alert('An error occurred!');
  }
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

if anyone can guide with the correct approach :-)

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Doesn't works mean the file is not getting uploaded to the target webserver